# Calling a static method in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nfc

I implemented a plugin (using pGina software) to allow the user to authenticate the username/password in their computer by scanning a NFC tag.

I used a program I found called [CSharp PC/SC Wrapper for .NET](http://www.smartcard-magic.net/en/pc-sc-reader/csharppcsc-wrapper/) to read the tag ID. Every time a tag is scanned the program writes the ID to a text file and checks that the ID is the the same as the one set on the string.

```
if (userInfo.Username.Contains("hello") && userInfo.Password.Contains("pGina") 
  && text.Equals("UID  = 0x04 82 EC BA 7A 48 80"))
```

The plugin is set to find the .exe file that reads the ID (PC/SC Wrapper). Everything works fine. However, I don't one the reader program to be in a different file. I want everything to be in the plugin file.

I created a method and copied the code from the wrapper that performs the reading of the tag ID (runme()), but I'm not sure how to replace the line that calls the .exe file with the method I created

`ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\CSharpPCSC\CSharpPCSC\ExamplePCSCReader\bin\Release\ExamplePCSCReader.exe");`

Any suggestions? I'm new to C#

Below is my code for the plugin with the method containing the code that reads the ID

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using pGina.Shared.Types;
using log4net;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using GS.PCSC;
using GS.Apdu;
using GS.SCard;
using GS.Util.Hex;
using System.Threading;

namespace HelloPlugin
{
    public class PluginImpl : pGina.Shared.Interfaces.IPluginAuthentication
    {
        private ILog m_logger;

        private static readonly Guid m_uuid = new Guid("CED8D126-9121-4CD2-86DE-3D84E4A2625E");

        public PluginImpl()
        {
            m_logger = LogManager.GetLogger("pGina.Plugin.HelloPlugin");
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "Hello"; }
        }

        public string Description
        {
            get { return "Authenticates users with 'hello' in the username and 'pGina' in the password"; }
        }

        public Guid Uuid
        {
            get { return m_uuid; }
        }

        public string Version
        {
            get
            {
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
        }

        public void Starting()
        {

        }

        public void Stopping() { }

        public BooleanResult AuthenticateUser(SessionProperties properties)
        {

            UserInformation userInfo = properties.GetTrackedSingle<UserInformation>();

            ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\CSharpPCSC\CSharpPCSC\ExamplePCSCReader\bin\Release\ExamplePCSCReader.exe");
            Process.Start(ps);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\text.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
            text = text.Trim();

            if (userInfo.Username.Contains("hello") && userInfo.Password.Contains("pGina") && text.Equals("UID  = 0x04 82 EC BA 7A 48 80"))
            {
                // Successful authentication
                m_logger.InfoFormat("Successfully authenticated {0}", userInfo.Username);
                return new BooleanResult() { Success = true };
            }
            // Authentication failure
            m_logger.ErrorFormat("Authentication failed for {0}", userInfo.Username);
            return new BooleanResult() { Success = false, Message = "Incorrect username or password." };
        }

        static void runme()
        {
            ConsoleTraceListener consoleTraceListener = new ConsoleTraceListener();
            Trace.Listeners.Add(consoleTraceListener);

            PCSCReader reader = new PCSCReader();
            string cardid = "";

            try
            {
                reader.Connect();
                reader.ActivateCard();

                RespApdu respApdu = reader.Exchange("FF CA 00 00 00"); // Get NFC Card UID ...
                if (respApdu.SW1SW2 == 0x9000)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("UID  = 0x" + HexFormatting.ToHexString(respApdu.Data, true));
                    cardid = "UID  = 0x" + HexFormatting.ToHexString(respApdu.Data, true);
                    cardid = cardid.Trim();
                }
            }
            catch (WinSCardException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.WinSCardFunctionName + " Error 0x" +
                                   ex.Status.ToString("X08") + ": " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                string path = @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\text.txt";
                string text2write = cardid;

                System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
                writer.Write(text2write);
                writer.Close();

                reader.Disconnect();
                Environment.Exit(0);
                Console.WriteLine("Please press any key...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a class called `PluginImpl` and in that class declared the method `runme`. To call that method from anywhere, you need to write `PluginImpl.runme()`.

Since you've put your class in the namespace `HelloPlugin` - if the calling `*.cs` file is in a different namespace, you'll need a `using HelloPlugin` directive at the top.

That's all!

It's possible I have misunderstood your question, if so please re-word your question and send me a comment.

---

If you want to replace the line

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(
         @"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\CSharpPCSC\CSharpPCSC\"
        +"ExamplePCSCReader\bin\Release\ExamplePCSCReader.exe");
```

with a method call instead, you want something like this

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = runme();
```

Since you are calling your static method from within the class, you don't need a `PluginImpl.` prefix.

Okay, so now it will complain that runme doesn't return ProcessStartInfo. You're going to need to change runme so that it does. Any subclass of ProcessStartInfo will do.

```
static ProcessStartInfo runme()
{
   // ... Some code

   ProcessStartInfo toReturn = new ProcessStartInfo( //...
   );

   // ... More code

   return toReturn;
}
```

Comment: Once I use PluginImpl.runme() how can I replace the ProcessStartInfo() to call the method.                                                             
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Users\Student\Desktop\CSharpPCSC\CSharpPCSC\ExamplePCSCReader\bin\Release\ExamplePCSCReader.exe");

Comment: @mj_h I hope my recent edits have resolved your question. If that is still not clear let me know.